# R time series data, daily only working days

Tags: r, date, sequence

I am using the following code:

```
dates<-seq(as.Date("1991/1/4"),as.Date("2010/3/1"),"days")
```

However, I would like to only have working days, how can it be done?
(Assuming that 1991/1/4 is a Monday, I would like to exclude: 1991/6/4 and 1991/7/4.
And that for each week.)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok, you just mean to exclude weekends? Look at the function `weekdays`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would this work for you? (note, it requires the timeDate package to be installed)

```
# install.packages('timeDate')
require(timeDate)

# A ’timeDate’ Sequence
tS <- timeSequence(as.Date("1991/1/4"), as.Date("2010/3/1"))
tS

# Subset weekdays
tW <- tS[isWeekday(tS)]; tW
dayOfWeek(tW)
```

Comment: @BrunoGG, you are welcome. renumber to mark your question as solved when your problem have been solved.

Answer (score 7):

You are entering your dates incorrectly. In order to use the YYYY/DD/MM input mode which is implied by 1991/1/4 being Monday, you need to have a format string in as.Date.

So the full solution assuming you want to exclude *weekends* is:

```
 X <- seq( as.Date("1991/1/4", format="%Y/%m/%d"), as.Date("2010/3/1", format="%Y/%m/%d"),"days")
weekdays.X <- X[ ! weekdays(X) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday") ]  
        # negation easier since only two cases in exclusion
        # probably do not want to print that vector to screen.
str(weekdays.X)
```

Regarding your comment I am unable to reproduce. I get:

```
> table(weekdays(weekdays.X) )

   Friday    Monday  Thursday   Tuesday Wednesday 
     1000      1000       999       999       999
```

Comment: Thank you DWin! However, I seem to be getting daily data with the week ends included.

Comment: @BrunoGG Check the printout of weekdays(X). You probably have weekdays in a different language

Answer (score 5):

I came to this question while looking up business day functions, and since the OP requested "business days" instead of "weekdays", and `timeDate` also has the `isBizday` function, this answer uses that.

```
# A timeDate Sequence
date.sequence <- timeSequence(as.Date("1991-12-15"), as.Date("1992-01-15"));  # a short example period with three London holidays
date.sequence;

# holidays in the period
years.included <- unique( as.integer( format( x=date.sequence, format="%Y" ) ) );
holidays <- holidayLONDON(years.included)  #  (locale was not specified by OP in question nor in profile, so this assumes for example: holidayLONDON; also supported by timeDate are: holidayNERC, holidayNYSE, holidayTSX & holidayZURICH)

# Subset business days
business.days <- date.sequence[isBizday(date.sequence, holidays)]; 
business.days
```

Comment: Extremely helpful with the holidays. Any suggestions for compiling a custom holiday list, such as day after Thanksgiving, etc.?