# How to subset xts by Date sequence that considers business days

Tags: r, date, subset, xts

I am subsetting an `xts` object by using an as.Date sequence:

```
library("quantmod")

getSymbols("AAPL",from="2003-01-01")
# indx sequence
indx <- seq(as.Date('2003-03-31'), length.out=200, by='4 weeks')

SELECT <- AAPL[paste(indx)]
```

If you take a look at the last 2 rows in `SELECT`, I see that it jumps from `2016-06-06` to `2016-08-01` which is not 4 weeks. It is missing `2016-07-04` but since that is not a business day it skips it. How can I return `SELECT` that will return the next available business day if `indx` is not a business day? in this example it should return `2016-07-05`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By business day, I guess you mean a trading day for `AAPL`, in which case your business days are really the time indices of the AAPL security.

First principles kind of approach using the fact dates can increment by 1 :

```
indx <- seq(as.Date('2003-03-31'), length.out=200, by='4 weeks')
indx <- indx[indx < as.Date(end(AAPL))]
while(!all(indx %in% as.Date(index(AAPL)))) {
    # You ask for the next available business day:
    indx[!indx %in% as.Date(index(AAPL))] <- indx[!indx %in% as.Date(index(AAPL))] + 1
    # Careful that the last indx value does not go past as.Date(end(AAPL))
    if (indx[length(indx)] > as.Date(end(AAPL))) {
        indx[length(indx)] <- as.Date(end(AAPL))
    }
}

SELECT <- AAPL[indx]
tail(SELECT)
# AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
# 2016-03-14    101.91    102.91   101.78     102.52    25076100     101.35055
# 2016-04-11    108.97    110.61   108.83     109.02    29407500     107.77640
# 2016-05-09     93.00     93.77    92.59      92.79    32936400      92.29005
# 2016-06-06     97.99    101.89    97.55      98.63    23292500      98.09858
# 2016-07-05     95.39     95.40    94.46      94.99    27705200      94.47819
# 2016-08-01    104.41    106.15   104.41     106.05    38167900     105.47860
```

You might also find solutions via `timeDate` package useful more generally for business date type subsetting.  e.g.  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673895/r-time-series-data-daily-only-working-days](http://timeDate%20examples)